# Assign a variable for the key-assign-list of \DTLforeach

Tags: macros, expansion, datatool

Please consider the following MWE-1:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{datatool}
\newcommand*{\myKeyOne}{ID}
\newcommand*{\myKeyTwo}{First-Name}
\newcommand*{\myKeyThree}{Last-Name}
\newcommand*{\myHeaderOne}{\myKeyOne}
\newcommand*{\myHeaderTwo}{\myKeyTwo}
\newcommand*{\myHeaderThree}{\myKeyThree}

%There are two external files, my-CSV-File-A.txt and my-CSV-File-B.txt

%The contents of my-CSV-File-A.txt are
%ID,First-Name,Last-Name
%1,First-Name-One,Last-Name-One
%2,First-Name-Two,Last-Name-Two
%3,First-Name-Three,Last-Name-Three
%4,First-Name-Four,Last-Name-Four
%5,First-Name-Five,Last-Name-Five

%The contents of my-CSV-File-B.txt are
%ID,First-Name,Last-Name
%6,First-Name-Six,Last-Name-Six
%7,First-Name-Seven,Last-Name-Seven
%8,First-Name-Eight,Last-Name-Eight
%9,First-Name-Nine,Last-Name-Nine
%10,First-Name-OneZero,Last-Name-OneZero

%For MWE purposes, only 5 entries are shown in each file after the header/keys line. In reality, each file can contain up to 1000 lines.

%Using datatooltk, the following .dbtex files are generated:
%
%my-CSV-File-A.dbtex
%my-CSV-File-B.dbtex
%
%The corresponding database names are the same as the filenames.

%Load the databases:

\input{my-CSV-File-A.dbtex}%
\input{my-CSV-File-B.dbtex}%

\begin{document}
%Now, present the databases in tabular format:
This is for database {my-CSV-File-A}.
\begin{longtable}{ccc}%
\hline%
\myHeaderOne&\myHeaderTwo&\myHeaderThree%
\tabularnewline%
\hline%
\endfirsthead%
\hline%
\myHeaderOne&\myHeaderTwo&\myHeaderThree%
\tabularnewline%
\hline%
\endhead%
\DTLforeach*{my-CSV-File-A}%
{%
\myColumnOneValue=\myKeyOne,%
\myColumnTwoValue=\myKeyTwo,%
\myColumnThreeValue=\myKeyThree%
}%
{%
\myColumnOneValue&\myColumnTwoValue&\myColumnThreeValue%
\tabularnewline%
\hline%
}%
\end{longtable}

This is for database {my-CSV-File-B}.
\begin{longtable}{ccc}%
\hline%
\myHeaderOne&\myHeaderTwo&\myHeaderThree%
\tabularnewline%
\hline%
\endfirsthead%
\hline%
\myHeaderOne&\myHeaderTwo&\myHeaderThree%
\tabularnewline%
\hline%
\endhead%
\DTLforeach*{my-CSV-File-B}%
{%
\myColumnOneValue=\myKeyOne,%
\myColumnTwoValue=\myKeyTwo,%
\myColumnThreeValue=\myKeyThree%
}%
{%
\myColumnOneValue&\myColumnTwoValue&\myColumnThreeValue%
\tabularnewline%
\hline%
}%
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

There is no problem with MWE-1. It compiles just fine. Now, suppose I have many databases/tables with the same headers/keys, and suppose there are also many headers/keys, and there are thousands of row entries. Some tables are a result of sorting, some a result of shuffling, and perhaps some a result of filtering. Thus, they all have the same headers/keys, and perhaps I desire to display them. To minimize errors, I considered using variables for the headers/keys and rows.

Consider now MWE-2:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{datatool}

\newcommand*{\myKeyOne}{ID}
\newcommand*{\myKeyTwo}{First-Name}
\newcommand*{\myKeyThree}{Last-Name}

\newcommand*{\myHeaderOne}{\myKeyOne}
\newcommand*{\myHeaderTwo}{\myKeyTwo}
\newcommand*{\myHeaderThree}{\myKeyThree}

\newcommand*{\myHeader}{\myHeaderOne&\myHeaderTwo&\myHeaderThree}

\newcommand*{\myRow}{\myColumnOneValue&\myColumnTwoValue&\myColumnThreeValue}

\newcommand*{\myKeyAssignList}%
{%
\myColumnOneValue=\myKeyOne,%
\myColumnTwoValue=\myKeyTwo,%
\myColumnThreeValue=\myKeyThree%
}%

\input{my-CSV-File-A.dbtex}%
\input{my-CSV-File-B.dbtex}%

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{ccc}%
\hline%
\myHeader%
\tabularnewline%
\hline%
\endfirsthead%
\hline%
\myHeader%
\tabularnewline%
\hline%
\endhead%
\DTLforeach*{my-CSV-File-A}%
{\myKeyAssignList}%
{%
\myRow%
\tabularnewline%
\hline%
}%
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{ccc}%
\hline%
\myHeader%
\tabularnewline%
\hline%
\endfirsthead%
\hline%
\myHeader%
\tabularnewline%
\hline%
\endhead%
\DTLforeach*{my-CSV-File-B}%
{\myKeyAssignList}%
{%
\myRow%
\tabularnewline%
\hline%
}%
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

It seems that introducing `\myHeader` and `\myRow` is ok, but the introduction of `\myKeyAssignList` resulted in non-compilation.

If I use a function instead, e.g.,

```latex
\newcommand*{\myLongTableFunction}[5]%
{%
\begin{longtable}{#2}%
\hline%
#3%
\tabularnewline%
\hline%
\endfirsthead%
\hline%
#3%
\tabularnewline%
\hline%
\endhead%
\DTLforeach*{#1}%
{#4}%
{%
#5%
\tabularnewline%
\hline%
}%
\end{longtable}
}%
```

and call the following:

```latex
\myLongTableFunction{my-CSV-File-A}{ccc}{\myHeader}{\myKeyAssignList}{\myRow}%
\myLongTableFunction{my-CSV-File-B}{ccc}{\myHeader}{\myKeyAssignList}{\myRow}%
```

it does not compile.

After much trial-and-error, I figure the error is in `\myKeyAssignList`. It seems I cannot “convert” the key-assign-list into a variable.

Is there a way I can assign a variable for the key-assign-list of `\DTLforeach`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question shows an effort of clarity and moderate abstraction, which is good. I would appreciate it, however, and you would probably get more readers in the future, if you could make it shorter and with a self-contained example, as mine below. See how I use, for instance:

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{file-A.csv}
...
\end{filecontents*}
```

to include both of your database files along with the LaTeX document (such files are written when you compile the document and they don't already exist, by default; there is an `overwrite` option that may be used when really needed).

I believe that your main problem is that you think that TeX macros work like functions in most programming languages, where evaluating an expression such as `f(a, b, c, ...)` evaluates the arguments `a`, `b`, `c`, etc. *before* `f` is called. TeX is a macro language and doesn't work this way; macro arguments are simply *substituted* for the `#1`, `#2`, etc. placeholders at the time a macro is expanded. For example, with the definition:

```latex
\newcommand*{\zzz}[1]{abc#1def}
```

one expansion step of `\zzz{1+1}` yields `abc1+1def`, and one expansion step of `\zzz{\what\ever}` yields `abc\what\ever def` (internally, there is no space after `\ever`: this is only “user-level syntax” to make it clear that the control sequence name stops after `ever`). This is *pure textual substitution*, regardless of whether we could “compute” `1+1` or expand `\what\ever`. Such expansion doesn't happen automatically. When it is needed to comply with the syntax of a particular macro (in your case: `\DTLforeach*`), you need to handle the expansion yourself.

Some commands automatically perform expansion on some of their arguments, that is why this doesn't always seem to be needed. But except in `expl3` documentation, this fact is rarely documented, so you need to:

- explicitly handle expansion to prepare the arguments yourself, or;
- inspect the code you are using to determine if, and how it expands its arguments, or;
- try to determine this information by trial and error (not great).

When only one expansion step on the first argument is needed, `\expandafter` makes the job easy:

```latex
\expandafter\someMacro\expandafter{\myMacro}{other arguments...}
```

When only two expansion steps on the first argument are needed, you can modify this a little bit:

```latex
\expandafter\someMacro
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\myMacro}{other arguments...}
```

but readability is clearly decreasing. When more expansion steps are needed or when other arguments than the first need to be expanded, other techniques are more practical (`\edef`, exchanging arguments in intermediate macros, token list registers...). The `expl3` language has a very elegant and general solution to this problem: function variants. Read about it [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/l3kernel) and read my second example below if you are interested; adding more details in this post would get us way too far.

In your case, you want to pass precisely these tokens as the second mandatory argument of `\DTLforeach*`:

```latex
\myColumnOneValue=ID,\myColumnTwoValue=First-Name,\myColumnThreeValue=Last-Name
```

This is quite different from passing `\myKeyAssignList`, which is a single token, even if `\myKeyAssignList` expands to the above tokens. Therefore, I define a wrapper macro called `\myDtlIteration` as follows:

```latex
\newcommand*{\myDtlIteration}[2]{%
  \DTLforeach*{#2}{#1}%
    {%
      \myRow
      \tabularnewline
      \hline
    }%
}
```

Inside the `longtable`, I expand `\myKeyAssignList` *before* the wrapper macro is itself expanded. The wrapper macro receives the one-step expansion of `\myKeyAssignList` as its first argument. Thus, the wrapper macro's `#1` is precisely the desired tokens `\myColumnOneValue=ID,\myColumnTwoValue=First-Name, etc.`; therefore, this is what `\DTLforeach*` will get as its second mandatory argument.

With these explanations and the comments in the code below, I believe you should understand. Note that you don't need to use `%` at the end of a line if the last token is a `\controlword`, i.e., a control sequence token whose name only contains letters (a-z and A-Z).

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{file-A.csv}
ID,First-Name,Last-Name
1,First-Name-One,Last-Name-One
2,First-Name-Two,Last-Name-Two
3,First-Name-Three,Last-Name-Three
4,First-Name-Four,Last-Name-Four
5,First-Name-Five,Last-Name-Five
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{file-B.csv}
ID,First-Name,Last-Name
6,First-Name-Six,Last-Name-Six
7,First-Name-Seven,Last-Name-Seven
8,First-Name-Eight,Last-Name-Eight
9,First-Name-Nine,Last-Name-Nine
10,First-Name-OneZero,Last-Name-OneZero
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLloaddb{my-db-A}{file-A.csv}
\DTLloaddb{my-db-B}{file-B.csv}

\newcommand*{\myKeyOne}{ID}
\newcommand*{\myKeyTwo}{First-Name}
\newcommand*{\myKeyThree}{Last-Name}

% Beware, this doesn't “store” the current values of \myKeyOne, \myKeyTwo and
% \myKeyThree! You would need to expand them before executing the definition
% for that.
\newcommand*{\myHeaderOne}{\myKeyOne}
\newcommand*{\myHeaderTwo}{\myKeyTwo}
\newcommand*{\myHeaderThree}{\myKeyThree}

% Ditto: \myHeaderOne, \myHeaderTwo and \myHeaderThree aren't expanded now.
\newcommand*{\myHeader}{\myHeaderOne&\myHeaderTwo&\myHeaderThree}

% Ditto
\newcommand*{\myRow}{\myColumnOneValue&\myColumnTwoValue&\myColumnThreeValue}

\newcommand*{\myDefineAssignList}[4]{%
  \newcommand*{#1}% use \def#1{...}% if you want to be able to overwrite #1
    {%
      \myColumnOneValue=#2,%
      \myColumnTwoValue=#3,%
      \myColumnThreeValue=#4%
    }%
}

% If you have more than 8 columns, we'll need a different syntax (e.g.,
% \myDefineAssignList{\myKeyAssignList}{<comma-list>}).
\myDefineAssignList{\myKeyAssignList}{ID}{First-Name}{Last-Name}
% Use this to check the result:
% \show\myKeyAssignList

\newcommand*{\myDtlIteration}[2]{%
  \DTLforeach*{#2}{#1}%
    {%
      \myRow
      \tabularnewline
      \hline
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{ccc}%
    \hline
    \myHeader
    \tabularnewline
    \hline
  \endfirsthead
    \hline
    \myHeader
    \tabularnewline
    \hline
  \endhead
    \expandafter\myDtlIteration\expandafter{\myKeyAssignList}{my-db-A}%
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{ccc}%
    \hline
    \myHeader
    \tabularnewline
    \hline
  \endfirsthead
    \hline
    \myHeader
    \tabularnewline
    \hline
  \endhead
    \expandafter\myDtlIteration\expandafter{\myKeyAssignList}{my-db-B}%
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In case you really want to use:

```latex
\myDefineAssignList{\myKeyAssignList}{\myKeyOne}{\myKeyTwo}{\myKeyThree}
```

instead of:

```latex
\myDefineAssignList{\myKeyAssignList}{ID}{First-Name}{Last-Name}
```

then, to be on the safe side, the three arguments `\myKeyOne`, `\myKeyTwo` and `myKeyThree` passed to `\myDefineAssignList` must be expanded once before we use the result of these expansions to define `\myKeyAssignList`. This is relatively easy to do using `expl3` as I said, with either an `o` or a `V`-type argument (`V` will behave better if you pass `expl3` integer variables for instance; that is why I chose it here):

```latex
\usepackage{xparse}

(...)

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Nn \beethov_define_assign_list:Nnnn
  {
    % Use \cs_new:Nn if you want to have an error when #1 is already defined
    \cs_set:Npn #1
      {
        \myColumnOneValue=#2,
        \myColumnTwoValue=#3,
        \myColumnThreeValue=#4
      }
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \beethov_define_assign_list:Nnnn { NVVV }

\NewDocumentCommand \myDefineAssignList { m m m m }
  {
    \beethov_define_assign_list:NVVV #1 #2 #3 #4
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\myDefineAssignList{\myKeyAssignList}{\myKeyOne}{\myKeyTwo}{\myKeyThree}
```

The full code with this technique:

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{file-A.csv}
ID,First-Name,Last-Name
1,First-Name-One,Last-Name-One
2,First-Name-Two,Last-Name-Two
3,First-Name-Three,Last-Name-Three
4,First-Name-Four,Last-Name-Four
5,First-Name-Five,Last-Name-Five
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{file-B.csv}
ID,First-Name,Last-Name
6,First-Name-Six,Last-Name-Six
7,First-Name-Seven,Last-Name-Seven
8,First-Name-Eight,Last-Name-Eight
9,First-Name-Nine,Last-Name-Nine
10,First-Name-OneZero,Last-Name-OneZero
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLloaddb{my-db-A}{file-A.csv}
\DTLloaddb{my-db-B}{file-B.csv}

\newcommand*{\myKeyOne}{ID}
\newcommand*{\myKeyTwo}{First-Name}
\newcommand*{\myKeyThree}{Last-Name}

% Beware, this doesn't “store” the current values of \myKeyOne, \myKeyTwo and
% \myKeyThree! You would need to expand them before executing the definition
% for that.
\newcommand*{\myHeaderOne}{\myKeyOne}
\newcommand*{\myHeaderTwo}{\myKeyTwo}
\newcommand*{\myHeaderThree}{\myKeyThree}

% Ditto: \myHeaderOne, \myHeaderTwo and \myHeaderThree aren't expanded now.
\newcommand*{\myHeader}{\myHeaderOne&\myHeaderTwo&\myHeaderThree}

% Ditto
\newcommand*{\myRow}{\myColumnOneValue&\myColumnTwoValue&\myColumnThreeValue}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Nn \beethov_define_assign_list:Nnnn
  {
    % Use \cs_new:Npn if you want to have an error when #1 is already defined.
    \cs_set:Npn #1
      {
        \myColumnOneValue=#2,
        \myColumnTwoValue=#3,
        \myColumnThreeValue=#4
      }
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \beethov_define_assign_list:Nnnn { NVVV }

\NewDocumentCommand \myDefineAssignList { m m m m }
  {
    \beethov_define_assign_list:NVVV #1 #2 #3 #4
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% If you have more than 8 columns, we'll need a different syntax (e.g.,
% \myDefineAssignList{\myKeyAssignList}{<comma-list>}).
\myDefineAssignList{\myKeyAssignList}{\myKeyOne}{\myKeyTwo}{\myKeyThree}
% Use this to check the result:
% \show\myKeyAssignList

\newcommand*{\myDtlIteration}[2]{%
  \DTLforeach*{#2}{#1}%
    {%
      \myRow
      \tabularnewline
      \hline
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{ccc}%
    \hline
    \myHeader
    \tabularnewline
    \hline
  \endfirsthead
    \hline
    \myHeader
    \tabularnewline
    \hline
  \endhead
    \expandafter\myDtlIteration\expandafter{\myKeyAssignList}{my-db-A}%
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{ccc}%
    \hline
    \myHeader
    \tabularnewline
    \hline
  \endfirsthead
    \hline
    \myHeader
    \tabularnewline
    \hline
  \endhead
    \expandafter\myDtlIteration\expandafter{\myKeyAssignList}{my-db-B}%
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same as above.

Comment: thank you for your help. i guess it will take sometime for me to digest your solution. thank you for the kind reminders for me to keep myself short and concise, for greater clarity.